# Delete multiple images using php

Tags: php

Hi Could you please help,
I'm building a website using php (my first time please be gentle)
within the site I upload an image tohe server, to a file called inventory_images,
on it's way itgets resized, so I end up with two images
img01.jpg and resized_img01.jpg
I use the small one for the frontend to speed loading, the large one I use for when the viewer wishes to see the full sized imaged.

I use the code below,

```
// unlink the image from server
// Remove The Pic -------------------------------------------
    $pictodelete = ("../inventory_images/$id_to_delete.jpg");
    if (file_exists($pictodelete)) {
    unlink($pictodelete);
                }
    header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
     exit();
```

to remove the image from the inventory image file, how can I get the delete to also take out the resized file, so both are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would do it to delete all images in a certain directory and remove the links from the database too

```
function deleteImage($image, $link)
{
    unlink($image);
    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `image_link` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($link) . "'");
    return (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Wadie,but would this delete ALL images? or just the selected image and it's resized version, I only ask because there are about 60 other images and resized versions in the same file that we obviously need to keep for the rest of the site.

Comment: This deleted all the images including the resized versions,but I thought you had all the images you wanted to remove in one directory.

Comment: Hi Wadie,our images are stored in a folder on the server (not in the db) and retrieved with the text through an id. So for instance, an advert with an id of 01, when called will also bring with it any images from the inventory_image folder with the ref img01 or resized_01. So I need to be able to select specifically a pair of images for deletion, my original code allows me to select one of the images, what I need is a way of saying "select one image and it's resized version for deletion" but that leaves all other images in-place.